# 404 error after trying to install free SSL (using https://zerossl.com/) in C-Panel

Tags: ssl, https, http-status-code-404, magento2, mixed-content

1) After following the steps in this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GPcznB74GPs) on how to install free SSL using ZeroSSL, I encounter a problem that shows 404 Not Found in my website. Although i enter https://(my_domain_name).com manually in the URL, it still doesn't show the HTTPS. In my C-Panel>SSL STATUS>I can see that my domain is validated (with a green lock beside it)

2) At the end of the tutorial in the video, there is some codes that need to be placed inside .htaccess file (in the public_html root directory) in order to automatically change the URL into https:// URL. (Tutorial code as below)

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

I have previously installed magento 2 and the .htaccess have its own similar code. (Magento 2 code as below)

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

1) There are others that encounter the same problem and provide their solutions like rename my file /.well-known/acme-challenge/(FILE NAME.txt) to /.well-known/acme-challenge/(FILE NAME), however, mine does not have a .txt to begin with. There is another video that says to rename the pictures/source which had http in it to https by inspecting the page>console (It will shows mixed-content warning). However, mine does not show any mixed content warning.

2) When i tried to replace and/or add the above magento 2 code with the tutorial code, I got too_many_redirect error.

My website/domain name is www.aevuswebs.com

Comment: Magento redirects in .htaccess leave unchanged. Have you set up SSL in the Magento panel? Have you checked whether in addition to the public_html directory you do not have another directory on FTP, for example private_html? If so, a symbolic link will be needed. For the test, add a simple index.html file there and check if it is displayed.

Comment: Thank you so much @JarekBaran. I did not set up the SSL in the Magento Admin panel. After configure the base url into https, the my website works fine. Thank you so much for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to database of your **Magento** & search for the table **`Core_config_data`** with in that table look for the rows with the current URL details of your website that is without SSL.

Update the detail & add 's' into both secured & unsecured base_url's something like below

```
http://www.example.com/   ->   https://www.example.com/
```

Try to reload your website it will load.